# Load Pages Using AJAX to Allow for a Continuous Music Player

Tags: ajax

I'm looking to create a music player that will play continuously between page loads. After some research, I've decided AJAX is the best way to do this.

I'm looking to load all the site content using AJAX (minus the music player) in one container  and place the music player in a separate container div at the bottom of the page.

How would this be done? Thanks is in advanced!

Comment: from a high level, what you would have to do is write a javascript/jquery function that would intercept/take over every single `<a href="....">` in your page that belongs to your site, so that instead of going to that page it instead loads it into your content container.  You would also have to look for every site anchor tag that shouldn't open in there, eg, ajax calls in forms for auto repeat or flags that use a menu callback to increment them and make sure they work.  and then you would have to look for anchors that go to external pages and make sure they open in another window.

Comment: you may want to look at grooveshark's and paste magazine's websites for some inspiration

Comment: Thanks, for now I've settled on using Enhanced XSPF Player With Autoresume. Figured this was the easiest solution for now. 

I will take a look at Grooveshark though. 

Support.http://www.boutell.com/xspf/

Answer (score 1):

To quote my answer to the same question at StackOverflow:

> [Ajax pages](http://drupal.org/sandbox/jamix/1988012) makes it possible to load every page via Ajax with minimum effort. A player can be put in a region outside of the Ajax-loaded area, making for continuous playback. There are demo links on the project page, check them out.